# How to sort order of bars and legend with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, bar-chart

How do I get the bar values sorted (decreasing) by value by one of the groups (e.g. teacher)? and How do I change the label so the top bar is also the top label in the legend? I tried changing it before creating the dataset by ordering the categories right but I did not change the bar chart for some reason-

```
`df <- data.frame(Category = c("A","B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), 
                 Student = c(4.4,3.35,5.96,2.07,4.56,3.55), 
                 Teacher = c(3.21,4.39,5.3,1.8,2.8,3.14))

data.m <- melt(df, id.vars='Category')[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhsCP.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhsCP.png)

ggplot(data.m, aes(y = reorder(Category, value), x = value)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = variable),
           position = position_dodge(width = 0.6), width = .6
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(label = value, group = variable),
            hjust = -0.2, size = 2.5,
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.6)
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0, .05, 0)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues") +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(title = "Students and Teachers", x = "Category", y = "Means", fill = NULL)
`
```

I tried reordering by changing;...aes(y = reorder(Category, -value), x = value)).. but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You could reorder you bars by the teacher values only by using an `ifelse` to set the student values to zero for reordering. And to fix the order of the legend you could reverse the order using `breaks=rev`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(
  data.m,
  aes(
    y = reorder(Category, ifelse(variable == "Teacher", value, 0), FUN = sum),
    x = value
  )
) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = variable),
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.6), width = .6
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(label = value, group = variable),
    hjust = -0.2, size = 2.5,
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.6)
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0, .05, 0)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues", breaks = rev) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(title = "Students and Teachers", x = "Category", y = "Means", fill = NULL)
```

[image]